# SQL select maximal value from Table

Tags: t-sql, max

On one of my interviews I was asked how it's possible to select 
maximal value from DB without keyword `MAX` and `TOP`.

My answer was:

```
select Table.Value 
from Table 
where Table.Value >= all( select Table.Value from Table)
```

But this wasn't the right one. The interviewer said that 
I should do it only with one select.

Any ideas ?

Thank you ;)

Comment: Possibly wants you to use `row_number`? `MAX` and `TOP` would both be more efficient. Also what do you mean by "one `SELECT`". With a CTE the `SELECT` keyword appears twice. Once for the definition and once to `SELECT` from it but it isn't really 2 `SELECT` operations.

Comment: I mean there is one "nested" select.

Comment: I don't find those types of interview questions useful.  How often would that particular tidbit of knowledge come in useful?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about;

```
select -min(-fld) from table
```

<strike>Less efficient & uglier</strike> *Woops missed the single select restriction*

```
select distinct Value from Table T
  where not exists (select Value from Table where Value > T.Value)
```

Comment: Could you please explain this ?

Comment: If you have a set [1,5,9] then transform it to [-1,-5,-9] the lowest (min()) number is -9, flip the sign (-min()) to get 9 back again

Comment: The second one would be dismissed on the same grounds the OP's solution was. But the first one is a brilliant workaround!

Comment: @Andrei I think if you'd have been suggest this solution they would have hired you without any other question:). Awesome solution...

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT t1.Value
FROM atable t1
 LEFT JOIN atable t2 ON t1.Value < t2.Value
WHERE t2.ID IS NULL
```

Answer (score 2):

One suggestion (if you use MySQL, I put limit also):

```
SELECT table.value FROM table ORDER BY table.value DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: Well, I think that TOP and LIMIT are both prohibited.

Comment: @Andrei If you remove limit you will still have the first result (of multiple ones) as the highest ;). But however, you must be sure that he restricted `limit` also, which does not make sense to me...

Comment: I understand, but there was question only about one row.

Answer (score 2):

```
SET ROWCOUNT 1

SELECT number 
FROM master..spt_values
ORDER BY number DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

order the result set by the key, descending, nulls last.
That makes the row with the max, first.

select the first row, and you are done.

Comment: How do you select the first row?